# VSCode selecting SCSS class does not work

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello I have a problem with SCSS when I want to choose class with double ' - ' it does not work. Sidebar class has an orange class but `--active` is red. If i use only one '-' it is ok. Anyone knows why?

```
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10;
    left: 0;
    height: 70vh;
    max-width: 10vh;
    background-color: white;

    &--active {
     margin: 10rem;
    }

    &--icon {
            width: 3rem;
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="sidebar">
            <svg class="sidebar--icon"><use href="{% static 'home/sprite.svg' %}#icon-user"></use></svg>
            <svg class="sidebar--icon"><use href="{% static 'home/sprite.svg' %}#icon-menu"></use></svg>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html for the classes as well to understand the context better?

Comment: Yeah sure. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link for reference- [SCSS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector). Both `.sidebar-icon` or `.sidebar--icon` classes are fine and will work.

The `:active` pseudo-selector is a CSS property and to use it the convention will be `&:active` which in CSS translates to `.sidebar:active`. If you want to use `:active` on the `sidebar--icon`, then you have to apply `&:active` to the inner nested child.
Please check this example with sample circle icons:

```
    <div class="sidebar">
       <svg class="sidebar--icon" viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
      </svg>
      <svg class="sidebar--icon" viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
      </svg>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .sidebar {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 50vh;
   max-width: 10vh;
   background-color: white;

  &:hover {
   margin: 1rem;
   background-color:orange;
   }

   &--icon {
        width: 20rem;
        margin-right: 2px;

        &:hover{
            width: 15rem;
        }

        &:active{
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

     }

 }
```

Comment: --active would be a class for javascript manipulation so i think it can be here.